# Mac 13inch 2020 model-M1chip- Lenovo USB C gen2 dock station--> Unable to connect dual monitors

Tags: mac, dock

I have Mac 2020 model, 13 inch & M1 chip model and using Lenovo Dock station- USB C model.

I am trying to connect my 2 external monitors, but after connection it is displaying duplicate on both the monitors.

I tried couple of options like with VGA cable, HDMI and other options, but still duplicate mirror is displaying.

Can any one suggest what is the work around to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can't connect two **external** monitors to M1 MacBooks with the extend mode. There exist a work around consisting of connecting one monitor through USB-C and the other with the help of DisplayLink software, but I do not know how good is this working. Possibly, we will see Big Sur update for 2020 MacBooks that enables 2 external monitors in extended mode.